How to represent a checkbox correctly in XSD?
I have a checkbox on the UI with 3 values A,B,C. I would like to create an XSD that describes this data set I know that this is a very basic question, but I did not find anything on this here.
What I already have is this:
<xs:simpleType name = "userType_SimpleType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            A = A type
            B = B type
            C = C type
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="B"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name = "userType_ListType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Possible values: A,B,C
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="userType" type="userType_SimpleType" minValue="1" maxValue="3" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:simpleType>

Although not sure that it is correct.

In my view a checkbox can have a boolean value true or false. Only for a group of checkboxes it makes sense that you want e.g. three different values for a group of three checkboxes.

And wouldn't it be a Radio button rather than checkbox if it can have 3 different values?  If you can select multiple, then you need to have an element for each one with a true/false value
